# Trello notifications in Facebook

Tags: facebook, trello, notifications

Is there a way to integrate Trello (or a Trello-like app) with Facebook so that users get notifications when there's new activity? Maybe even use the app directly in Facebook? If not, is such an app technically feasible?

Rationale for this question: There are lots of great project/task management web apps out there. But people don't like having to log into a separate site they wouldn't otherwise visit. This means that, unless the project is part of people's jobs, activity ends up decaying, and eventually dying off completely, at least in my experience with volunteer organizations. Email notifications try to counter this effect, but seem to be insufficient. If one could tap into the fact that most people use Facebook and login regularly, I expect this would keep the activity up.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Zapier.com](https://zapier.com).

"Zapier lets you easily connect the web apps you use, making it easy to automate tedious tasks."

Comment: I did look into it, and indeed it does support a trigger for both "any activity" and "notifications for you" from Trello, but the only action I could do with those is posting on my Facebook timeline. I could set those posts to be only visible to me, but I believe this doesn't generate a notification.

Besides, the hole thing is sort of a hack for achieving what I'm asking, and wouldn't allow me to post publicly to Facebook from Zapier using different triggers.

Comment: I wish you luck finding what you're looking for.